# Looking for suggestions on how to handle public facing object ids

Tags: php, mysql

I need help on coming up with a strategy to handle object ids in a PHP/MySQL application I'm working on. Basically, instead of having a URL look like this:

```
/post/get/1
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
/post/get/92Dga93jh
```

I know that security-through-obscurity is useless (I have an ACL system in place to handle security) but I still need to obscure the ids. This is where I'm stuck.

I thought about generating a separate public id for each DB row but have been unable to find a way to create truly unique ids.

I suppose I could encrypt and decrypt a MySQL auto increment row id as it leaves and enters my app, but I'm not sure how 'expensive' PHP's encryption and decryption methods are. Additionally, I need to make sure that the obscured id remains unique so that it doesn't decrypt into the wrong value.

Also, since my domain objects are related to each other, I want to avoid any unnecessary strain on MySQL if I decide to go with generating and storing an obscure id in the tables.

I'm beating my head against the wall because I feel like this is a common scenario, yet can't figure out what to do. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just use a salted md5. It's secure for 99% of the cases. The other 1% will be when you are wacking your head on the wall cause you got your data stolen by a pro-hacker and it becomes critical to minimize the impact of it.

So:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MD5(CONCAT(ID, "mysupersalt")) = "'.$my_checked_url_value.'"';
```

And generating the same thing from PHP can be done using similar strategy:

```
<a href="/link/to/mypage/<?php echo md5($id.'mysupersalt'); ?>"> link text </a>
```

Hope this is what you're looking for..

Answer (score 1):

As long as you given 9-char base62 string - you could follow this strategy:

1. Generate a number from 1 to 13537086546263552 (62 ^ 9)
2. Convert it to the base62 string
3. Try to insert to the database (you're supposed to have the unique index over id field)
4. If ok - do nothing
5. If not ok - repeat 1-3

Comment: One cannot generate numbers up to 62^9 with PHP. At least not with native methods like `rand()`

Comment: @TimWolla: `php -r "echo rand(1, pow(62, 9));" >> 13146801849083731`

Comment: You are using 64-bit, right? 32-bit does not support it. `php > echo rand(1, pow(62, 9));
-441682605
`

Comment: @TimWolla: yeah, it is 64b environment here. I just wanted to oppose that *it is* possible to do in php ;-)

Comment: Again learned something. I though PHP was 32bit only, even on 64bit OSs

Answer (score 1):

Use a one-way hash like md5, etc.

Comment: If it's a one-way hash, won't I be unable to decrypt it on the way back in?

Comment: Just store it in the table as if it were the row id... am I missing something in your use case?  you said, "I thought about generating a separate public id for each DB row but have been unable to find a way to create truly unique ids." - md5 is near enough to unique.

Comment: No, you're correct. I was in a rush when I wrote that comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the application really, if its super essential that you have IDs from which the user can never 'guess' the original IDs, then use a recursive call to db to generate a unique public ID.

If on the other hand, you just need the IDs to look different without any security worries if someone can 'guess' the original ID, and are concerned with the performance, you can come up with a quick and basic math equation to generate a unique id on the fly and decode it as well when the URL is accessed.

(I know its a HACK, but gets the job done for a lot of cases)

E.g. If I access `/blog/id/x!1@23409235` (which means `/blog/id/1`)

In the code, I can decode above by:

```
$blogId = intval(substr($_GET['id'], 4)) - 23409234;
```

and of course, while generating the URL, you add 23409234 to the original URL's id and prefix it with some random char bits..

Oh and you can use Apache's mod_rewrite to do all these calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The probably easiest way is checking whether there is already such a record in a

```
do {
    $id = generateID();
}
while(idExists($id));
```

loop. There shouldn't be to many duplicate IDs so in most cases there are only two queries most the time: Checking and Inserting.